# Ubuntu: why do I face the permission denied error when a program edits bash_profile

Tags: 14.04, bash, sudo

I was trying to install SugarLabs (a python project) there is a command in procedure:

```
./osbuild shell
```

which returns this output:

```
id: cannot find name for user ID 1001
id: cannot find name for group ID 1001
id: cannot find name for user ID 1001
/bin/bash: /home/broot/.bash_profile: Permission denied
/bin/bash: /home/broot/sugar-build/osbuild: Permission denied
```

It tries to edit the bash_profile or something.

How do I solve this?

I tried this:

```
ls -la ~ | grep bash
```

this is what I get:

```
-rw-rw-r--    1 username username         21 Jun 14  2016 .bash_aliases
-rw-------    1 username username       4419 Jun  8  2016 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--    1 username username        220 May 21  2016 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--    1 username username       3486 May 21  2016 .bashrc
```

no .bash_profile in this

Need help on this!

Comment: Hmm... that seems a bit strange to get a perms error instead of no such file, but I don't think we can help without seeing the script... where did you get the software?

Comment: here: https://developer.sugarlabs.org/dev-environment.md.html#shell

Comment: I reccomend taking a look at official docs. The had a repo for 14.04, and since 16.04 its included in ubuntu repos. https://wiki.sugarlabs.org/go/Ubuntu#OLPC_Ubuntu_Sugar_14.04_Trusty_LTS

Comment: @dgonzalez i did that..couldn't find..am stuck on this from a day

Comment: Looks like the script lacks write permission in /home/broot.

Comment: what happens when you run `nano .bash_profile`

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `ls -ld /home/broot`? Which user account owns the installer process, i. e. under which user account was it executed?